A book suggestion on additive number theory
I'm looking for a book on additive Number Theory, which has somewhat introductory spirit. In particular, I'm interested in Erdös-Ginzburg-Ziv theorem. I prefer a book that includes exercises. Thanks!

Some good books are mentioned here, including the book by Tao and Vu (or Tao's papers for more exercises).
